# library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac - Unity cloud build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have upgraded unity from `4.5.1` to `2007.0.1f3`, after this I am unable to make IOS build using Unity cloud build and getting this error

> library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac

I have used Google firebase and Facebook SDK in my project .

Post build script to transfer libs:

```c#
[PostProcessBuild]
 public static void OnPostprocessBuild (BuildTarget buildTarget, string path)
 {
     #if !UNITY_CLOUD_BUILD
     Debug.Log ("[UNITY_CLOUD_BUILD] OnPostprocessBuild");
     ProcessPostBuild (buildTarget, path);
     #endif
 }

 private static void ProcessPostBuild (BuildTarget buildTarget, string path)
 {
     #if UNITY_IOS
     string projPath = path + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";
     PBXProject proj = new PBXProject ();
     proj.ReadFromFile (projPath);
     // This is the Xcode target in the generated project
     string target = proj.TargetGuidByName("Unity-iPhone");
     proj.AddBuildProperty(target, "CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES", "YES");
     proj.AddBuildProperty(target, "OTHER_LDFLAGS", "-ObjC");
     proj.AddBuildProperty(target, "OTHER_LDFLAGS", "-v");
     List<string> frameworks = new List<string>() {
         "AdSupport.framework",
         "CoreData.framework",
         "SystemConfiguration.framework",
         "libz.dylib",
         "libsqlite3.dylib",
         "libGoogleAnalytics.a",
         "libGoogleToolboxForMac.a",
         "libApp.a",
         "libAnalytics.a"
     };
     frameworks.ForEach((framework) => {
         proj.AddFrameworkToProject(target, framework, false);
     });
     proj.WriteToFile (projPath);
     #endif
 }
```

What should I do to make IOS build from UBC?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Google uses Cocoapod to manage iOS dependencies. If you build locally, Unity should generate a **workspace** with your project and an associated project containing the pods (and in XCode you should open the workspace, not only your project).

From what I understand, Unity Cloud build isn't enable to do this, and a workaround for you could be to **use Firebase without cocoapods** : https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks.

## Update

Unity has [recently added Cocoapod support on unity cloud build](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/cocoapod-support-dependency-management).

Answer (score 0):

If you have zero knowledge in Xcode and don't want to figure it out, just follow this:

i. In your iOS project folder, double click the **Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace**, instead of **Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj** to open the Xcode.

ii. Cmd + R to run the game.